# Why does passing function parameters to a struct initialization return junk or seemingly not do anything?

Tags: c, struct, initialization

I'm trying to make a function in c to create and return a new struct similar to a constructor in OOP. When checking the variables the string is junk while the numbers are all 0. Can structs not be initialized using variables in c?

I've looked online for people who are trying a similar thing but they all use literals and strings to initialize theirs.

```
typedef struct tArtist{
    char realName[20];
    int accNum;
    double accBal;
    char telephoneNumber[15];
    double earningPerYear;
} Artist;




...

//function call
Artist artist = newArtist("Real Name", 123, 600.43, "1-(876)-362-2335", 999.99);

     Artist newArtist(char name[], int accountNum, double accountBal, char tele[], double earningPerYr) {
         Artist tempArtist = {name, accountNum, accountBal, tele, earningPerYr };


         return tempArtist;
     }
```

I expected as a test the realName to be "real name" but got X{XRc

Comment: We need a completely compilable example to tell exactly what is going wrong. Char arrays have a limited lifespan, so it could be that which is messing you up.

Comment: `name` and `tele` decay to `char *`, but you try to store them into arrays of `char`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `name` as the first value in the initializer of an `Artist`, you're trying to store a pointer in a char array.  That's an invalid initializer.

You need to set those fields explicitly:

```
 Artist newArtist(char name[], int accountNum, double accountBal, 
                  char tele[], double earningPerYr) {
     Artist tempArtist = {"", accountNum, accountBal, "", earningPerYr };
     strcpy(tempArtist.realName, name);
     strcpy(tempArtist.telephoneNumber, tele);

     return tempArtist;
 }
```

Comment: This fixed the issue but why did the numbers get affected? Also I understand what you're saying about storing the pointer but why doesn't it recognize it as a pointer to a string as is the case with regular string initializations?

Comment: @Deeswoc The compiler attempted to store value of the pointer in `realName[0]`, then the next inializer in `realName[1]` and so forth.  So it had cascading effects.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to achieve this would be to have your 'realName' and 'telephoneNumber' be pointers to character arrays, and then allocate the arrays in your constructor with the sizes that you want.

After that, use a strcpy() call to move your strings.